# Not getting header while converting html form values to csv

Tags: php, arrays, csv, header, forms

I am trying to get values in csv file from html form.
Following is the code I am using

my.php:

```
if($error == '')
{
    $file_open = fopen("contact_data.csv", "a");
    $no_rows = count(file("contact_data.csv"));
    if($no_rows > 1)
    {
        $no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) + 1;
    }
    $form_data = array(
        'sr_no'     =>  $no_rows,
        'name'      =>  $name,
        'email'     =>  $email,
        'subject'   =>  $subject,
        'message'   =>  $message
    );
    fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
    $error = '<label class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us</label>';
    $name = '';
    $email = '';
    $subject = '';
    $message = '';
}
```

but I am getting csv with no headers. (in csv format)

```
   test,test@g.com,test_sub,test_msg
   user,user@g.com,user_sub,user_msg
```

Expected Output: (in csv format)

```
    name, email,      subject,  message
    test, test@g.com, test_sub, test_msg
    user, user@g.com, user_sub, user_msg
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why the need for `$no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) + 1`? Surely that statement negates itself?

Comment: RohanR.Pawar is this code inside any loop? if not how multiple records as well as headings are saved? According to me this code will save only one record if it's not in a loop

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the associative array `$form_data` to the ***fputcsv*** function the way you do - `fputcsv($file_open, $form_data)`, it outputs only the *values* part of the associative array and not the *keys*.

So you will have to explicity add the keys write the *keys* part .i.e., the ***headers*** to the csv. You can do it in one of the following ways -

---

Fetch the keys dynamically and store it a separate array:

```
$keys = [];    // declare new array to store key values

foreach($form_data as $key => $value) {
    array_push($keys, $key);
}
```

Or harcode the keys into an array:

```
$keys = array('name','email','subject','message');
```

---

Now you can write to the csv file in the following way -

`fputcsv($file_open, $keys);`

And then write your second *fputcsv()* - `fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);`

It won't cause any problems because you have opened the csv file in "a" (append) mode.

Comment: `name,email,subject,message |
 test, test@g.com |
name,email,subject,message |
user, user@g.com, user_sub, user_msg`
  Header repeats for every new entry. I want it only once when file is created. I am entering the values in same CSV.